# What are some ways I can represent a weighted, directed graph in Java?

Tags: java, graph

I can't use any external libraries, so I'm trying to think of some ways to build the data structure myself. I was thinking maybe something like this:

```
public class Node{
    Set<Edge> adjacent;
    int value;
}

public class Edge{
    Node target;
    int weight;
}
```

But I'm guessing there's probably a better way to do it.

My eventual use for this graph is to run the Bellman Ford algorithm on it, but I obviously need a functioning graph first!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer depends a lot on the algorithms that you are planning to apply to your graphs.

There are two common ways to represent a graph - an [*adjacency list*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) and an [*adjacency matrix*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix). In your case, and adjacency matrix is a square array of integers representing weights. Your representation uses an adjacency list.

There are algorithms that work better on adjacency matrixes (e.g. Floyd-Warshall algorithm). Other algorithms work better on adjacency lists (e.g. Dijkstra's algorithm). If your graph is sparse, using adjacency matrix may be prohibitive.

Comment: @Hoser In most cases, the answer is "yes". Special cases, such as Floyd-Warshall, require a matrix to work. You can keep the adjacency list representation up until the point when you run the algorithm, build the matrix to run it, and finally convert the matrix back to an adjacency list.

Comment: Alright thank you. What about either of these makes them support direction? Do they actually enforce direction, or is that something I have to manage myself?

Comment: @Hoser Yes, they both support direction: a matrix has two distinct spots for storing edges from `A` to `B` (`matrix[A][B]`) and for edges from `B` to `A` (`matrix[B][A]`). The adjacency list is also directional - node `A` may have a different weight for its edge to `B` from the weight of the reciprocal edge (if there is one).

Answer (score 4):

As usual, you can represent graphs as Adjacency Lists or Adjacency Matrices. The choice really depends on the details of your problem.

Using an Adjacency Matrix, you could simply have a matrix of integers, representing the weight.

If you decide to have an Adjacency List, you could simply store a list of list of integers
(assuming the nodes of your graph are identified by an integer value), similar to what you've done.

Comment: Does an adjacency matrix support edge weights?

Comment: Yes, I corrected the answer. You can have the weights on the matrix (line X, col Y has the val Z, means the cost from X to Y is Z)

Comment: Alright thank you. Adjacency matrix seems like a good way to do this. How does it support the direction requirement? Is there any specific reason an adjacency matrix forces you to go a certain way between nodes, or is it just something I need to be sure to avoid.

Comment: The adjacency list you've suggested will only demonstrate an edge from A to B but what about the weight of those edges?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a node as in an unweighted graph, holding a list of nodes to which it is connected,and additionally add the weights associated with the connections as:

```
public class Node{
    int value;
    HashMap<Node,Integer> adjacency;
}
```